# Why do I need to look for a class in a jar file that is not included in the maven pom.xml file?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have imported a jar file in nexus, a local maven repository, and another jar file in the referenced lib via java build path.

The problem appears to refer to the class in the jar file referenced in the pom file of the Eclipse project at all, without using the classes in the referenced lib.

The same class exists in two jar files.

I do not know what caused the problem.

this is eclipse bug?

for example:

a.jar, b.jar -> both have ReferenceClass(same pacakages)

A project's pom.xml -> dependency a.jar

MyProject's referenced libraries -> dependency b.jar

my project:MyClass.java -> import ReferenceClass -> reference a.jar

[build path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sq3R.png)

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1ktl.png)

[pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEgam.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use "Referenced Libraries" in a Maven project. This will confuse Eclipse.

Furthermore, try to avoid having the same class twice in your classpath.

Comment: I changed to maven dependency as you said, but I have the same problem.

Comment: If you have the same class twice in different Maven dependencies, it is difficult to control which of these classes will be loaded. Try to avoid that situation if possible. Furthermore, if you have a concrete build problem, please post the result of `mvn clean package`.